# Problems with TYPO3 Route Enhancers

Tags: routes, yaml, typo3, typo3-9.x

I got the following yaml configuration, 
the Problem now is, that I dont get the Route Enhancer for CV-Action and Questionaire Action to work.
Show and Application Action works, so I get there a speaking URL like:

Show-Action: /job/kundenberater-in-e-commerce/

Application-Action: profil/kundenberater-in-e-commerce

but for questionaire for example it breaks:

?tx_jobboerse_displayjobs%5Baction%5D=questionnaire&tx_jobboerse_displayjobs%5Bcontroller%5D=jobs&tx_jobboerse_displayjobs%5Bjobs%5D=98&cHash=0fac7e52327d8ef84d8a650ceb885e73

Does anybody have an idea whats happened here?

```
routeEnhancers: 
 Jobboerse:
 type: Extbase
 limitToPages:
   - 14
   - 5
 extension: Jobboerse
 plugin: displayjobs
 defaultController: 'Jobs::list'
 routes:
   - { _controller: 'Jobs::show', routePath: '/job/{jobs_title}', _arguments: {'jobs_title': 'jobs'} }
   - { _controller: 'Jobs::application', routePath: '/profil/{jobs_title}', _arguments: {'jobs_title': 'jobs'} }
   - { _controller: 'Jobs::cv', routePath: '/cv/{jobs_title}', _arguments: {'jobs_title': 'jobs'} }
   - { _controller: 'Jobs::questionnaire', routePath: '/fragebogen/{jobs_title}', _arguments: {'jobs_title': 'jobs'} }
 aspects:
   jobs_title:
     type: PersistedAliasMapper
     tableName: tx_jobboerse_domain_model_jobs
     routeFieldName: path_segment
```

Comment: questionaire  !=  questionnaire , was that it only? Or did you set that right?

Comment: It´s copied from the action name. It doesnt work with cv also...Dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my Solution.
The Problem was I wrote the controller-name with lower case.

Set Controllername="Jobs" in every form works.